# c++ Inset and read Map element in protobuf3

Tags: c++11, protocol-buffers

Here is the `.proto` which have one map:

**map.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

package demo;

message Person {

  map<string, int32> family_list = 4;

}
```

Now I insert key and value from the Write_impl.cc

```
auto map = test.mutable_family_list();
string key = "faimly";
int val =20;
(*map)[key] = val;
std::cout<<"map = "<<(*map)[key]<<std::endl;
```

Below I read the value of key `family` in read_impl.cc

```
auto test = demo::Person::default_instance();
auto map = test.mutable_family_list();
std::cout<<"map = "<<(*map)["faimly"]<<std::endl;
```

**Problem: I get 0 when reading the value of key "family"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `demo::Person::default_instance()` which doesn't have the value you've stored earlier. It contains the default one.

You are using the subscript operator `[]` that doesn't throw an exception if the key is not found but the `at()` method does. You should use the `at()` method.

Here's an example of serialization and deserialization:

```
int main()
{
    // Serialization

    demo::Person sPerson;
    const auto mutable_family_list = sPerson.mutable_family_list();
    mutable_family_list->insert( { "abc", 42 } );
    std::cout << mutable_family_list->at( "abc" ) << '\n';

    const auto serialized = sPerson.SerializeAsString();

    // Deserialization

    demo::Person dPerson;
    if ( !dPerson.ParseFromString( serialized ) )
    {
        std::cerr << "Deserialization failed!\n";
        return -1;
    }

    const auto family_list = dPerson.family_list();
    std::cout << family_list.at("abc") << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
42
42
```

Alternatively, you can `find()` first and then use the value like this:

```
const auto it = family_list.find( "abc" );
if ( it != family_list.end() )
{
    std::cout << it->second << '\n';
}
```